# LWJGL OpenGL Projection Matrix Issue

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl, projection

I am coding a game in java and I recently tried adding the projection matrix,
so I am able to move objects with the Z axis and actually see the object get smaller, have FOV,
ect..

Now the problem is when I introduce this my object just doesn't render.
I've been following a nice tutorial series, I beleive I did everything correctly and double checked for two hours, trying new solutions.
I then gave up and had a look at LWJGL documentation.
Still doesn't render my object.

Here is my vertexShader code.

```c
#version 150 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec3 color;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    color = vec3(position.x+0.5,0.0,position.y+0.5);
}
```

This is my fragmentShader code

```c
#version 150 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
}
```

This is my renderer class.

```java
package me.purplex.jgame.renderer;

import me.purplex.jgame.entity.Entity;
import me.purplex.jgame.model.RawModel;
import me.purplex.jgame.model.TexturedModel;
import me.purplex.jgame.shaders.program.impl.StaticShader;
import me.purplex.jgame.utils.MathUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;

public class Renderer {

    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;

    public static final float FOV = 70;

    public static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;

    /**
     * VIEW DISTANCE
     */
    public static final float FAR_PLANE = 1000;

    public Renderer(StaticShader shader) {
        createProjectionMatrix();
        shader.start();
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
        shader.stop();
    }

    public void prepare() {
        GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void render(Entity entity, StaticShader shader) {
        TexturedModel model = entity.getModel();
        RawModel rawModel = model.getRawModel();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(rawModel.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = MathUtils.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(),
                entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getModelTexture().getTextureID());
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, rawModel.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private void createProjectionMatrix() {
        final float width = Display.getWidth();
        final float height = Display.getHeight();

        final float fieldOfView = Renderer.FOV;
        final float aspectRatio = width / height;
        final float nearPlane = Renderer.NEAR_PLANE;
        final float farPlane = Renderer.FAR_PLANE;

        final float yScale = (float) coTanget(Math.toRadians(fieldOfView / 2f));
        final float xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
        final float frustumLength = farPlane - nearPlane;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 =xScale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = yScale;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((farPlane + nearPlane) / frustumLength);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * nearPlane * farPlane) / frustumLength);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    }

    private double coTanget(double rads) {
        return (1.0 / Math.tan(rads));
    }
}
```

This is my main loop

```java
DisplayManager.createDisplay();
float[] vertices = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};
int[] indices = {
        0, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2
};
float[] textureCoords = {
        0, 0,
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        1, 0
};
ModelLoader modelLoader = new ModelLoader();

StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();

Renderer renderer = new Renderer(shader);

RawModel model = modelLoader.loadToVAO(vertices, textureCoords, indices);

TexturedModel staticModel = new TexturedModel(model,new ModelTexture(modelLoader.loadTexture("image")));

Entity entity = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(0, 0, -1), 0, 0, 0, 1);
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    renderer.prepare();
    shader.start();
    renderer.render(entity, shader);
    shader.stop();
    DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
}
shader.cleanUp();
modelLoader.cleanUp();
DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
```

Why? I am kind of annoyed.
In my `vertexShader` when I remove the `projectionMatrix` part, everything works fine but I can't have a projection matrix!
When I add it my object is not rendered at all, all I see is my red background.
If someone can help it would mean the world!
Thank you.

All I see is my red background but no image.

[image]

Comment: Are you following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP) by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am @Sweeper

Comment: This is my first time using LWJGL.

Comment: I was in the middle of episode 8, he ran, his object rendered but mine didn't.
I won't continue while mine isn't working. Edit: here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50Y9u7K0PZo&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=8

Comment: What is `entity.getPosition()`? The object has to be in between the near and far plane of the frustum else the object is clipped. The view space z axis points out of the viewport, thus the z coordinate of `entity.getPosition()` has to be negative. You have to fulfill the following condition: `near < -entity.getPosition().z < far`

Comment: entity.getPosition() is a Vector3f, a vector with 3 floats

Comment: @Rabbid76 (I'm not the OP but I followed the same tutorial) Entity's z coordinate should be -1.

Comment: Check the main loop code.
The entity object takes in a Vector3f and my static shader class.
The vector3f entered in the entity is the getPosition().

Comment: Btw the Z is -1

Comment: @Sweeper It should, but is it? I recommend to set `z = -(NEAR_PLANE + FAR_PLANE )/2` for debug reasons. _-(near+far)/2_ is in the center of the frustum.

Comment: Try setting the z position even further back, like -10.

Comment: I tried -10, haha, that also didn't work :c

Comment: I tried removing the projectionMatrix, rendering the image worked just fine, I could rotate, just as you know z axis won't work as no projectionMatrix.

I recoded the projectionMatrix with lwjgl's docs, the code here are from lwjgl's docs

Comment: @Rabbid76 Your debugging value still doesn't render it.
I dont see anything just a red background, i added a picture so you can see.

Comment: Ofcourse scale is 1

Comment: @purplex Possibly the issue is related to the transformation matrix. Try the following for debug reasons: `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position.xy, position.z-5.0, 1.0);`

Answer (score 0):

A perspective projection matrix can be defined by a [**frustum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).
The distances `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top`, are the distances from the center of the view to the side faces of the frustum, on the near plane. `near` and `far` specify the distances to the near and far plane of the frustum.

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

x:    2*n/(r-l)      0              0                0
y:    0              2*n/(t-b)      0                0
z:    (r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    -1
t:    0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)     0
```

If the projection is symmetrical and the line of sight is the axis of symmetry of the frustum, the matrix can be simplified:

```
a  = w / h
ta = tan( fov_y / 2 );

2 * n / (r-l) = 1 / (ta * a)
2 * n / (t-b) = 1 / ta
(r+l)/(r-l)   = 0
(t+b)/(t-b)   = 0
```

The symmetrically perspective projection matrix is:

```
x:    1/(ta*a)  0      0              0
y:    0         1/ta   0              0
z:    0         0     -(f+n)/(f-n)   -1
t:    0         0     -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

Thus your computation of `yScale` is wrong:

<s>`yScale = (float) coTanget(Math.toRadians(fieldOfView / 2f));`</s>

```java
yScale = 1.0f / (float)coTanget(Math.toRadians(fieldOfView / 2f));
```

Comment: Do you think this caused it to render at all?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work bro, here is my new code.
I mention again, when I remove the projectionMatrix * in my vertexShader.txt,
that is only when the entity renders. ;/
[hastebin link](http://hasteb.in/enolulex.cs)

Comment: Here is my DisplayManager incase for some weird reason I am doing something wrong, following tutorials this should be correct?
http://hasteb.in/iyikehiv.java

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to clarify the issue has been resolved, I forgot to call a method initiating all uniform variables I am surprised some stuff still worked.
Thanks for helping me though!